# Python Azure service bus lock has been expired

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using azure service bus, I am getting lock has expired.

How ever I have implemented lock to 1 day, but still I am getting error

my code:

```
import json
from typing import Any, Dict, Generator, List, Optional


from azure.servicebus import (AutoLockRenewer, ServiceBusClient,
                              ServiceBusMessage)


class Queue():
    def __init__(
                self,
                connection_string: Optional[str] = None,
                queue_name: Optional[str] = None,
                max_lock_renewal_duration: Optional[int] = 86400,
                logging_enable: Optional[bool] = True
            ):
        

        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.logging_enable = logging_enable
        self.max_lock_renewal_duration = max_lock_renewal_duration
        self.client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
            conn_str=self.connection_string, logging_enable=logging_enable)
        self.sender = self.client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=self.queue_name)
        self.renewer = AutoLockRenewer(
                max_lock_renewal_duration=max_lock_renewal_duration)
        self.receiver = self.client.get_queue_receiver(
            queue_name=self.queue_name, auto_lock_renewer=self.renewer)

 
    def get_msgs(
                self,
                max_message_count: Optional[int] = 1,
                max_wait_time: Optional[int] = 5
            ) -> Generator[ServiceBusMessage, None, None]:
        

        for msg in self.receiver.receive_messages(
                    max_message_count=max_message_count,
                    max_wait_time=max_wait_time
                ):
            yield msg

     def abandon_msg(self, msg: ServiceBusMessage) -> None:
    

          self.receiver.abandon_message(msg)

q = Queue(connection_string="secret",
          queue_name="my_queue",
          logging_enable=True
        )
for msg in q.get_msgs(max_message_count=100, max_wait_time=5):
    print("process my messages")
    print("some reason abondan")
```

Error:

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/test/.env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_servicebus_receiver.py", line 782, in abandon_message
self._settle_message_with_retry(message, MESSAGE_ABANDON)
File "/test/.env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_servicebus_receiver.py", line 415, in _settle_message_with_retry
error=message.auto_renew_error,
azure.servicebus.exceptions.ServiceBusError: The lock on the message lock has expired.

My goal is to abandon message so that it will retry, also is there a way we can increase retry time instead of immedetly queued like delay 300 seconds for each abandon_msg?

Answer (score 0):

By default, lock period will be set as 30 seconds and we can increase that till 5 min.

Setting the lock period for 1 day will be denied from the console itself, as below screenshot:

[image]

Below screenshot after updating to max lock time:

[image]

However, locks can be renewed until the function completes. As we can use the automatic lock-renewal feature where you can specify the time duration for which you want to keep getting the lock renewed.

Below code will help us to [automatically renew the lock](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/index.html#automatically-renew-message-or-session-locks) on the session for 100 seconds

```
renewer.register(receiver, receiver.session, max_lock_renewal_duration=100)
print('Register session into AutoLockRenewer.')

received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
time.sleep(100)  # message handling for long period (E.g. application logic)
for msg in received_msgs:
    receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

To understand more about each parameter, refer to [auto_lock_renew.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-servicebus_7.3.3/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/auto_lock_renew.py#L74) from azure-sdk-for-python.

Also check the definition of  [_auto_lock_renew_task](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/8568a833322f777087df2097e8dc8cc22cd67750/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/_common/auto_lock_renewer.py#L39) from here.

**Suggestion**: Try to increase the Lock Period and reduce the renewlockperiod.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: AutoLockRenewer only supports registration of types azure.servicebus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage,  i guess it is message right? not receiver.session